# Phonegap with facebook login

Tags: cordova, single-sign-on, phonegap-plugins, facebook-login

I had followed the link -

https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/blob/962eb0a1c07935ff813e28aa9eaa5581f2e10416/README.md

install facebook login to PhoneGap.

Afterwards, I copy the sample "Scrumptious" from the plugin folder "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect". Also, I had updated the "App ID" in index.html.

However, I still got error with log as below. I try to ask Google but I still fix this problem. Please help.

> 2014-04-21 20:02:04.247 HelloWorld[29811:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device:
>   YES, App: YES
>
> 2014-04-21 20:02:04.259 HelloWorld[29811:60b] Unlimited access to
>   network resources
>
> 2014-04-21 20:02:04.614 HelloWorld[29811:60b] Resetting plugins due to
>   page load.
>
> 2014-04-21 20:02:04.847 HelloWorld[29811:60b] Init FacebookConnect
>   Session
>
> 2014-04-21 20:02:04.848 HelloWorld[29811:60b] ERROR: Method 'init:'
>   not defined in Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect

'

Comment: Your Cordova version?

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I have the same :(

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this exact same error, and couldn't find a fix anywhere, but it turns out the error was due to how I was attempting to use the plugin.

If you access the facebook plugin's methods via window.facebookConnectPlugin you will no longer see the error and it should work fine, trying to access the plugin's methods via the FB object or CDV.FB you will receive the error and things will just not work for you.

Not sure if that'll help you, but you're the only other person I saw posting the same error and that's how I got around it, so hopefully it'll work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

The "init" method is needed no more since new APIs get application id from app_id string property (in strings.xml)
And use facebookConnectPlugin instead of FB

Please, see changes here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/pull/351

Comment: Ok I am having same issue so I thought I should remove the init line but then realized that was the only place where app id was written. I re-read your comment and realized you have mentioned something about strings.xml. I am not sure what you meant by that. I would highly appreciate if you could elaborate on strings.xml as I can't find that file in my project. Btw i am currently trying to implement this for iOS. Thanks